# 1120 Access of undefined property Ibar & Ipc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

```
stop();


import flash.display.*;

this.stop();


this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, PL_LOADING);

function PL_LOADING(event: ProgressEvent): void {
    var pcent: Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal * 100;

    lbar.scaleX = pcent / 100;

    lpc.text = int(pcent) + "%";

    if (pcent == 100) {
        this.gotoAndStop(2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll do well to enable "Permit Debugging", however, the issue is on lines 14 & 15.  It means you don't have an object in memory by those names.  If you're working in the Flash IDE, and these are symbols in your library, add them to the stage, the and issue will be resolved.

Comment: Good point @Atriace. When dealing with a confusing compiler error you want to enable permit debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this code structure looks a bit disorganized. I'm not sure whether a lot of these changes will matter (since I currently don't have access to flash), but here is how I would typically write this:

```
stop();
import flash.display.*;
//no need for this.stop() if you've already stopped

this.loaderinfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,PL_LOADING);

function PL_LOADING(e:ProgressEvent):void{
//possibly part of the problem is that the var keyword was on the wrong line
var pcent:Number = e.bytesLoaded/e.bytesTotal*100;
ibar.scaleX=pcent/100;
ipc.text=String(int(pcent)+"%");
//typically you want to make it clear that it's a string when dealing with text fields
if(pcent==100){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

Small changes like these as well as thoughtful organization could save your code. If you're still having problems with your code just notify me and I'll try to help you out.